# Return documents filtered by column after $text search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing $text search on my collection where I have made compound text index. What I'm doing is a workaround for something (I think) I can't achieve otherwise. What I initially wanted was $text search on a field (column) given by user. But I guess that's not possible as their are around 4 text fields and I guess mongodb doesn't work that way.
So now, what I'm trying to do is that I want to search across all the fields and then filter out the documents which have the search-keywords matches in the user specified column.

I have coded until the full text search, but I'm not sure how to do the document filter thing. Is it possible?

my indices: `Details.collection.createIndex({ name: 'text', desc: 'text', bio: 'text'})`

collection documents:

```
{ "name" : "kat saphire",    "desc" : "I guess that's how it works",  "bio": "Creating a life, I love"}
{ "name" : "john doe",    "desc" : "I practice what I post", "bio": "Simplicity is the key to happiness"}
{ "name" : "kat lisa",    "desc" : "to be or not to be",   "bio": "In a world of worriers, be a warrior"}
{ "name" : "david beckham",  "desc" : "Live as if you were to die tomorrow",   "bio": "I practice what I post"}
{ "name" : "aura leo",    "desc" : "That which does not kill us makes us stronger", "bio": "She turned her can't into can and her dreams into plans"}
```

my keyword search: `practice what I post`

full text search results:

```
{ "name" : "john doe",    "desc" : "I practice what I post", "bio": "Simplicity is the key to happiness"}
{ "name" : "david beckham",  "desc" : "Live as if you were to die tomorrow",   "bio": "I practice what I post"}
```

Now I want results for one column only i.e e.g 'desc'

so my desired output should have:

```
{ "name" : "john doe",    "desc" : "I practice what I post", "bio": "Simplicity is the key to happiness"}
```

I have used aggregate to get my results so far.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Either $text is not the right too or mongo is not the right tool.

Comment: you mean for only 1 document i think, and `$limit` i guess

Comment: I want to search whatever user has given as input in columns (fields) of a collection using $text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const regex = { $regex: `${searchWord}`, $options: 'i' }
await db.collectionName.aggregate([{$match: { desc: regex }}])[0]
```

Comment: Can you please explain the [0] at the end?
Also wouldn't regex be slow here?